# Programming from scratch

Tags: c++, c, computer-science

What I would like to know is to start programming from scratch without any Operating System and anything like it.

As I know Windows and Mac and almost anything even the DOS is written in C, C++ Pascal etc., so I think I should know one of these languages, but for this I would need a program where I can write the code, and also to compile it but without an Operating System and programs how can be this done? How could they do it?

But this is not enough far, how was C written? in what? So when I mean scratch I mean, building everything from the basics. Maybe from `0,1,0,1` right now I think this is the exact start point. But how can I do it, what should I have and where should I start?

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: All you need is a magnetized needle and a steady hand: http://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: An operating system was written in Pascal?

Comment: @John: Yes.  MacOS. (Well, more than any other OS anyhow)

Comment: @neo2862: Awesome. XKCD is the most awesome page on the web... Besides StackOverflow, of course.

Comment: *If you want to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first create the universe* -- Carl Sagan [This is extensible to anything you want to make from scratch, and *this* is really an answer]

Comment: @John Dibling: Also, both Pascal's successor Modula-2 and Modula-2's successor Oberon were *specifically* designed for writing operating systems. Prof. Niklaus Wirth was working to invent personal computing in Zürich at around the same time Alan Kay and his group did in Palo Alto and these languages were the "full-stack" (i.e. everything from the operating system to the compiler, IDE, editor, GUI and applications) languages for Lilith and Ceres, the two workstation systems Wirth designed after two sabbaticals with Alan Kay at Xerox PARC. The OS/400 kernel was also Modula-2, originally.

Answer (score 16):

There's a *great* textbook called [*The Elements of Computing Systems: Building a Modern Computer from First Principles*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262640686) by Noam Nisan and Shimon Schocken, which serves as the basis for a university course taught by the authors called *Workshop In Computer Construction - From `NAND` to Tetris in 12 Steps*.   This course is also taught at other universities under different names.

There's a [10 minute introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlPj5Rg1y2w) on YouTube and a [1 hour Google TechTalk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JtXvUoPx4Qs) on Google Video, both by the author himself.

The official companion web site is http://nand2tetris.org/

Don't let the title "Computer Construction" fool you. By "computer", the author does not just mean the rectangular plastic box on your desk, he means the entire *computing system*, from the individual logic gates up to highest-level application programming.

The book/course teaches you

- how to create your own individual logic gates
- how to build your own logic circuits
- how to build your own CPU
- how to program in machine code directly
- how to program in your own assembler (which you wrote in machine code)
- how to write your own virtual machine
- how to design, implement and program in your own high-level language (which you wrote in assembler)
- how to write a bootloader
- how to write an operating system
- and ultimately how to write a simple game

Comment: thanks very much for your answer @Jörg W Mittag this book looks very interesting , your list about what can I learn from the book looks very cool, this is exactly what I'm looking for, I hope If I will get this book a day it will help me!

Comment: Google Video died long ago. This appears to be a working replacement: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlPj5Rg1y2w

Answer (score 11):

You can acquire a microcontroller prototyping board such as [`Arduino`](http://arduino.cc/),  [`Beagleboard`](http://beagleboard.org/) or [`MPLAB PIC board`](http://www.sparkfun.com/categories/6), and then create a [`machine monitor program`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code_monitor) that can load and execute your other programs in [`user space`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space).

You can program those microcontrollers in C or their respective [`instruction sets`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set).

[`Hook up an LCD display`](http://www.arduinoprojects.com/node/13) to that MCU board and you have a monitor. [`Hook up a keyboard and mouse`](http://www.practicalarduino.com/projects/ps2-keyboard-or-mouse) to it and you have controls. (You can even write your own [`trap handlers`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trap_%28computing%29) for writing to LCD and reading inputs from keyboard and mouse to understand how interrupts and exceptions work at low level. If you want to go lower, you will have to look at MCU pin-outs for interrupt control lines and timing diagrams).

Voilà! You've designed your own computer from scratch!

To answer your question about C, compilers for the first programming languages were written in [`assembly`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_language), and compilers for assembly were written in [`machine code`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set).

Comment: cool, thanks very much for your answer @vls , lots of links and resources thanks very very much!

Answer (score 8):

what you're talking about used to be called a 'monitor' program. you might get some interesting info at osdev.org and taking a look at colorforth.

[afterthought] google Rick Hohensee's ramblings on comp.lang.forth also.

[much later afterthought] to really get to basics, get a plug-in circuit breadboard, some old EPROMs, a 5VDC power supply and a 25VDC power supply (24 ought to work, it's more common). Use pullup or pulldown resistors on the address and data lines, and switches to supply ground or power to the address and data lines. Step through the addresses using the switches, and enter the data as ones and zeros on the data bus, programming each with a pulse from the 25V. I've never actually done this manually, but I once wrote a program (http://jc.unternet.net/hacks/?1994-01-01-01) to do this from a Centronics port, and burned several programs that way. This was back in the day when Intel would send you free books for all their processors and auxiliary chips, complete with detailed instruction sets and timing.

When done, connect your processor to the EPROM, give it some juice, and watch what happens. Maybe make it strobe some LEDs or something before you start trying to integrate keyboards and monitors.

Comment: Thanks very much @jcomeau_ictx osdev.org looks very interesting! and I will look after this forth language too

Comment: I'd love to see that LED-based self-soldered monitor! I actually saw something like that a long time ago...

Answer (score 4):

The problem you're describing is most commonly referred to as [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) (and its' relationship to the [chicken and egg problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_and_egg)).  That specific link is for compilers, but you have the same problem in many areas - hardware, operating systems, etc., with similar solutions.

Comment: yeah this is something like that, chicken and egg :D, thanks very much for the bootsrapping word and link, because I didn't even know that this word exists

Answer (score 4):

Beginning at the basics is `1` and `0`. You need to know what instructions your processor supports and what registers and cache, etc. exist. Then it would be handy to write a little assembler compiler in machine code (for readable `1` and `0`). If you have that, you can write the first real compiler for a simple higher language, and so on (each built using a lower-level "language"). You should know, though, that creating a simple operating system can take years of planning and even more time to develop, debug, etc. (and all this before you can even think of seeing something useful on the screen). And that operating system won't be able to run on any other processor than yours. Then you need drivers, etc for every single bit of hardware. And there are many steps to go from here. Beginning at the level of `1` and `0` is not very rewarding, since you won't see anything of it for a very long time. Simply **don't.**

Comment: I wouldn't say don't do it; I would just advise not to expect any spectacular results :)

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I still think that you shouldn't do that until you know _exactly_ what you're doing. I added that advise, though ;)

Comment: Well, I think nothing is impossible. And learning never hearts ;) however you pushed me forward with your words so thank you!

Comment: @CIRK: It is not impossible, of course. I think it could be a quite good thing to look into, but i recommend not to waste a _lot_ of time on building this system yourself from the ground up. It'll only frustrate you. Keep in mind that operating systems are one of the most difficult programs to write. It is enough to know how it works in most cases ;)

Comment: @elusive I think it's never enough to know how it works, just some examples it's not enough to know how democracy works if we don't use it, or it's not enough to know how to live if we don't live. And it's never enough if we want to create something new or better ;)

Comment: @CIRK: True. I wish you good luck with your operating system :) I'd love to see the result! Feel free to send me a copy. I volunteer for beta-testing!

Comment: @elusive :D I will I promise!

Comment: CIRK's question is one of more interesting I`ve found. 
@elusive: your answer explained very well what the question wanted to know I think....
I'm studying Operating System but I've always thought about this chicken and egg issue and no books explained this!
(or well until I've red of course lol)
I apologize for my english :P

Answer (score 3):

Most C compilers can emit code that's not designed to run in the context of an OS (see the `memtest86+` codebase for example), but that's going to severely limit the feature set provided by any of those compilers. (In particular, you're not going to get anything like `malloc`).

Comment: thanks I will look after these!

Answer (score 3):

You can't do what you seek terribly conveniently on most modern PC-style computers, but there are many inexpensive (sub-$100, or even sub-$50) kits available for programming smaller single-chip micros.  A typical micro will have a few dozen pins which can be driven high and low under program control, along with a processor, some RAM (typically 256 bytes-8K or so), and some flash memory for code (typically 8K-128K or so).  The development kits will typically have a processor with some pins attached to LEDs or an LCD display, and with other wires attached to a few buttons.  The boards will also include circuitry so you can develop your software on a PC, connect a USB cable, and transfer your code into the chip.

Embedded programming is fun.  Gives some of the feel of 'old-school' programming, with some newer modern conveniences.

Comment: thanks for your answer @supercat , Yes the old-school feeling this is what I feel right now and really attracts me, the hardware is a big question for me, because I have a MAC here, and as I heard and read here also if I really want it from scratch I need to work with the processor and so on, and I don't really want to crash my computer or anything, thanks very much for your tips!

Comment: @CIRK: BTW, if you want to go really old-school, go to AtariAge.com, and look for information about the Harmony cartridge.  Buy a Harmony cartridge along with an Atari 2600, and (with the aid of other info on the site) you can write your own games that will run on a game console built in 1977.  If you want to show much of anything on that system, you need to feed the data to the video chip in real time.  The processor is even responsible for generating vertical sync (fortunately, hardware takes care of horizontal sync).  Maybe I'm weird, but I love the 2600 as a programming platform.

Comment: @CIRK: With most video game systems, the design of the video chip controls what you can put on the screen, except on systems where everything is a bitmap and you can show whatever you want.  The Atari 2600 is pretty limited, but the only hard limit is that each scan line is only 160 pixels. The system was designed to show two movable single-color shapes per screen plus a couple movable blocks, but one of my games features 16 movable shapes (one moves anywhere, and five groups of three move horizontally at fixed vertical positions), with every shape colored independently on a per-line basis.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you get yourself a small microcontroller system to play around with. TI has a small system-on-a-usbstick based on the MSP430 for $20.
You do not need a compiler or an OS to run code on this system. In fact, with only 128 bytes of ram it would be a challenge to get an OS onto it.

If you really want to start from scratch, you the write down your program in assembly code on a piece of paper and translate it by hand to machine code. Then you type in the machine code in a hex editor to get your ones and zeroes. This is really taking it to the extreme and you will not learn anything from doing the machine code by hand. Writing a program in assembly code will teach you a lot, though.

You do need a tool to get your program into flash memory for the cpu to be able to execute it, but once the flash has been programmed, there are no tools, os or anything like that involved.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you about hardware but if you want to build your own operating system, you can do that. It's a lot of work, but very rewarding. jcomeau_itcx already mentioned osdev.org. There's also the alt.os.development newsgroup, although it's been extremely quiet over the past couple of years - but check out the archive if you can find it.

Sounds like you're not put off by all the "Don't do it!" warnings... that's good :-)  You can learn about boot sectors and write your own in a few days, and then you'll see something on the screen and know that you're on your way.

Many people recommend that you do not write your own boot sector, because it's not strictly part of the operating system. They recommend that you boot using GRUB or similar. I disagree, partly because I wanted to learn how the computer booted, but also partly because I found it easier to write my own boot sector than to figure out how to use GRUB!

C is the best language for writing an OS, because it's high-level enough for you to be productive but low-level enough for you to work directly on the processor. Many people use gcc, but you can also use Visual C++ or whatever (but compile in C, not C++, and you do need a compiler that supports inline assembler and can generate functions with no prolog/epilog.) You can write your code on your regular PC and then run it in a virtual machine - I prefer bochs because it's got a built-in debugger, but there are others.

Some tips for getting started on your OS (after you've sorted out your boot sector)... Intel IA32 is the most readily available processor (because it's in almost every PC) and most OS devers prefer it, so you can get more advice about it than about other platforms. I don't know whether they do this any more, but Intel sent me hard copies of their IA32 Software Developer's Manual - free of cost, but invaluable. You could work in real mode (16-bit, segments, no protection between apps... think Windows 3.1) but I reckon it's worth the effort to get into 32-bit protected mode (rather tricky) and be a bit more modern. Virtual memory (paging) is optional, but I did it because my original motivation for writing an OS was to learn just how 32-bit protected mode provided protection between apps.

It will be a long journey. I started my OS in 2004, working in the evenings, but then I started my business in 2006 and haven't had any time for it since. So it's a long way from being finished!

If you're curious, do it. You'll really enjoy it. And if you don't, you can stop.

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer , it motivates me , i'm happy to hear that you work on an os too!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, nothing you are describing exists in modern computers. Nowadays, you will always encounter layers of operating systems, bootstrapping, and possibly even virtualization between you and the hardware.

If you really want to understand the deep secrets of programming and how applications run on the hardware, I suggest you take an operating systems course or read up on how they work. For instance, the Andy Tanenbaum book Operating Systems Design and Implementation may be the ticket.

Comment: in modern days everything is based on the old days, and in the old days the old guys made if from scratch ;) Now the time has come to understand what they done and why is the world working in this way ;) thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get down to the hardware, try checking out microcontrollers like PIC and AVR. I recently had the chance to work with some of those platforms, where the code you write (in C or assembler) actually runs on bare metal.

Of course, that only means that you have to implement some core OS services yourself, like interrupt routines to handle input. Much of it is available as example code, but still small enough to read and understand the whole system.

As far as computer archaeology goes, try taking the basic courses in digital circuits, computer architecture and compiler technology at you nearest university. That satisfied my curiosity, as well as my need to write programs with raw binary opcodes :-)

Comment: thanks for your answer @Christoffer I will look after these microcontrollers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can program without a Operating System (OS), but the OS does the heavy lifting for you. For example with C (which you want to know) the magic it's not the language itself, but the compiler. Which basically what it does is something like this:

> C source code -> Non-optimized
>   intermediate code -> Optimize
>   intermediate code -> Machine code

Now, the Machine code goes to the OS, which itself uses it's own [Kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) for translating that Machine code, into binary form so the Hardware itself can understand what you want to do.

So basically before you write a program that runs without OS, you need to create your own compiler and a kernel for your machine to run it.

Comment: well you said in the first line that I cannot program without an Operating System, but in the last lines you said that I need to create a compiler and a kernel, and how should I make them without programming them?:O ;)

Comment: And what sort of OS would you for instance find in toys, calculators, coffee machines, etc? You definitely do not need an OS, or write your own compiler and kernel to execute it. You could write your program into a hex editor and put it in memory where the reset vector points and then pull the reset pin to execute your program.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the thing you say with the reset vector point if I'm not wrong is with pics, which is a completely different architecture. That's why toys,calcs,etc use PIC's not really under the vohn neumann architecture... @CIRK I'm sorry I wasn't thinking clearly, you CAN program without an OS what I mean to say was that the OS makes everything easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I made the beginnings of an operating system with a computer I designed and cobbled together years ago (I think that would be about 1985 or so). It is decent fun and you learn a lot doing it. Good success on your project!

The answers people have been giving you about a platform you could use to develop your operating system have been of the hardware variety. You would have to spend a bit of $$. Assuming you have access to a computer you might consider using a virtual computer like QEMU, or Oracle's Vbox and develop an os for that. If you have a mac, I really like Q as the interface makes the virtual computer even look like one. I think other posts here have probably mentioned osdev.org. That is a great place to bounce ideas off other DIYers, and get some help getting started. Good success to you.

CHEERS